# How to skipped if the column name are same in the datatable

Tags: c#

I'm using HTML Agility Pack to web scrape to datatable. However the website have multiple same column name which it was not able to add on for the second table.

The error will be prompt out like this as the "2020" had been added before
[image]

My code as below :

```
public void WebDataScrap()
        {
            try
            {
                //Get the content of the URL from the Web
                const string url = "https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/MY/XKLS/0146/financials/annual/cash-flow";
                var web = new HtmlWeb();
                var doc = web.Load(url);

                const string classValue = "cr_dataTable"; //cr_datatable
                //var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes($"//table[@class='{classValue}']") ?? Enumerable.Empty<HtmlNode>();

                var resultDataset = new DataSet();

                foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes($"//table[@class='{classValue}']") ?? Enumerable.Empty<HtmlNode>())
                {
                    var resultTable = new DataTable(table.Id);

                    foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("//tr"))
                    {

                        var headerCells = row.SelectNodes("th");
                        if (headerCells != null)
                        {
                            foreach (HtmlNode cell in headerCells)
                            {
                                resultTable.Columns.Add(cell.InnerText);           
                            }
                        }

                        var dataCells = row.SelectNodes("td");
                        if (dataCells != null)
                        {
                            var dataRow = resultTable.NewRow();
                            for (int i = 0; i < dataCells.Count; i++)
                            {
                                dataRow[i] = dataCells[i].InnerText;
                            }

                            resultTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

The URL i trying to web scrape : https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/MY/XKLS/0146/financials/annual/cash-flow

I did try to do looping to skip if it was having the same name but it will prompt that the column unable to find when I try to debug.

Is there any solution that can help to solve this? In the end I will need to export the datatable to csv/excel file.

Thanks

Comment: For every row in the table, you're trying to add all of the columns over and over? That would appear to be your problem...

Comment: @Llama Due to there are 3 table with same column, but the row are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do this instead:

```cs
foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes($"//table[@class='{classValue}']") ?? Enumerable.Empty<HtmlNode>())
{
    var resultTable = new DataTable(table.Id);

    // select all the headers and add them to the table
    var headerCells = table.SelectNodes("thead/tr/th");
    if (headerCells != null)
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode cell in headerCells)
        {
            resultTable.Columns.Add(cell.InnerText);
        }
    }

    // select all the rows and add them to the table
    foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tbody/tr"))
    {

        var dataCells = row.SelectNodes("td");
        if (dataCells != null)
        {
            var dataRow = resultTable.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataCells.Count; i++)
            {
                dataRow[i] = dataCells[i].InnerText;
            }

            resultTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
    }
}
```

The header section and the data section each have their own loop rather than the header section being nested in the data loop. We're also being more explicit about where we want data from: the header should come from `thead/tr/th` and the data should come from `tbody/tr`.

Comment: Nice! Let me try it out